# Why am I getting a "Class 'App\Providers\Form' not found" error in Laravel 5.5.43?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravelcollective

I did a Laravel 5.5.43 installation this morning with the following Composer command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name
```

I then ran the following command in the project folder to install Laravel Collective:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

I then added the following under `providers` in `config/app.php`:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

And I added the following under `aliases` in `config/app.php`:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

After that, I wanted to create custom form components, so I ran the following Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:provider FormServiceProvider
```

And in that new provider file, I added the following line to the `boot` method:

```
Form::component('customText', 'components.form.text', ['name', 'value' => null, 'attributes' => []]);
```

Lastly, I added the following to `providers` in `config/app.php`:

```
App\Providers\FormServiceProvider::class,
```

When I do that though and refresh the Laravel instance from the browser, I get the following error:

```
Class 'App\Providers\Form' not found
```

However, if I add the following at the top of the `FormServiceProvider.php` file, then it works:

```
use Collective\Html\FormFacade AS Form;
```

I understand the concept of namespaces and why that makes the `Form::component` method in the `boot` method in the file properly work, but what I don't get is why I need to add that `use` line to the file at all.

Isn't the `'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,` line in the `aliases` array in the `app.php` file supposed to do that for me so I don't need to add the `use` line to the `FormServiceProvider.php` at all? What am I missing / doing wrong / not understanding?

Thank you.

Comment: run php artisan config:cache

Comment: An alias is just a "shortcut". Instead of having to write `use Collective\Html\FormFacade` everytime you want to use it, you could just use your alias: `use Form`.

Comment: kerbholz, yes, you're right. Simply adding `use Form;` to the file works just fine. However, removing the line completely causes it to break. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I probably should just delete this question, but the simple answer was to add the following at the top of the `FormServiceProvider.php` file:

```
use Form;
```

Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. Clearing the cache returned the same error as Laravel will hit the same problem. The service provider required the Form class in it. Thanks @HartleySan

Answer (score 1):

Run below command:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: @HartleySan : If my answer is work for you then please accept my answer

Comment: Saurabh Dhariwal, unfortunately, that did not work. I tried it, but if I remove the `use Collective\Html\FormFacade AS Form` then I still get the error. Thanks.